# Evaluating a sum involving binomial coefficient in denominator

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, binomial-coefficients

I came across the following sum:
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)^2}\frac{4^k}{{2k \choose k}}$$

---

I thought that this can be evaluated using the expansion of $\dfrac{\sin^{-1}x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$ but I couldn't make any use of it. Then I tried to use the following:
$$\frac{1}{(2k+1)}\frac{1}{{2k \choose k}}=\frac{\Gamma(k+1)\Gamma(k+1)}{\Gamma(2k+2)}=\int_0^1 x^k(1-x)^k\,dx$$
but this didn't help either and now I am stuck.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

---

EDIT:

The sum originated from the following definite integral:

$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\tan^{-1}(\sin x)\,dx$$

Comment: https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL7/Sury/sury99.pdf

Comment: @labbhattacharjee: There is a lot of info in that paper, can you please point out the formula or identity I need to use here? Thank you!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

$$ \begin{align} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)^2}\frac{4^k}{{2k \choose k}} &= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k}}{2k+1} \int_{0}^{\pi /2} \sin^{2k+1} (x) \, dx  \\ &= \int_{0}^{\pi /2} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k} \sin^{2k+1} (x)}{2k+1} \, dx\\ &= \int_{0}^{\pi /2} \arctan (\sin x) \, dx \\ &= \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\arctan t}{\sqrt{1-t^{2}}} \, dt \end{align}$$

Let $ \displaystyle I(a) = \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\arctan (at)}{\sqrt{1-t^{2}}} \ dt$.

Then differentiating under the integral sign,

$$ \begin{align}  I'(a) &= \int_{0}^{1} \frac{t}{(1+a^{2}t^{2})\sqrt{1-t^{2}}} \, dt \\ &= \int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{[1+a^{2}(1-u^{2})]u} \, u \, du \\ &= \frac{1}{1+a^{2}} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{1-\left( \frac{au}{\sqrt{1+a^{2}}}\right)^{2}} \, du \\ &= \frac{1}{a \sqrt{1+a^{2}}} \text{arctanh} \left( \frac{a}{\sqrt{1+a^{2}}} \right) \\ &= \frac{1}{a\sqrt{1+a^{2}}} \frac{1}{2} \ln \Big((a+\sqrt{1+a^{2}})^{2} \Big) \\ &= \frac{1}{a \sqrt{1+a^{2}}} \ln \left( a+ \sqrt{1+a^{2}} \right) \\ &= \frac{1}{a \sqrt{1+a^{2}}} \text{arcsinh}(a) . \end{align}$$

And then integrating back,

$$ \begin{align} I(1)-I(0) = I(1) &= \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\text{arcsinh}(a)}{a \sqrt{1+a^{2}}} \, da \\ &= - \text{arcsinh}(a) \text{arcsinh}(\frac{1}{a}) \Bigg|^{1}_{0} + \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\text{arcsinh}(\frac{1}{a})}{\sqrt{1+a^{2}}} \, da \\ &= - \text{arcsinh}^{2}(1) +  \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\text{arcsinh}(\frac{1}{a})}{\sqrt{1+a^{2}}} \, da \\ &= - \ln^{2}(1+\sqrt{2}) + \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\text{arcsinh}(\frac{1}{a})}{\sqrt{1+a^{2}}} \, da . \end{align}$$

Now let $ \displaystyle w = \frac{1}{a}$.

Then

$$ I(1) = - \ln^{2}(1+\sqrt{2}) + \int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{\text{arcsinh}(w)}{w \sqrt{1+w^{2}}} \, dw$$

$$ =  - \ln^{2}(1+\sqrt{2}) + I(\infty) - I(1) .$$

Therefore,

$$ \begin{align} I(1) &= - \frac{\ln^{2}(1+\sqrt{2})}{2} + \frac{I(\infty)}{2} \\ &= - \frac{\ln^{2}(1+\sqrt{2})}{2} + \frac{\pi}{4} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t^{2}}} \, dt \\ &= - \frac{\ln^{2}(1+\sqrt{2})}{2} + \frac{\pi^{2}}{8} . \end{align}$$

Comment: Awesome! Never thought about evaluating it this way, thank you Random Variable! :D

Comment: @PranavArora You're welcome.

Comment: @RandomVariable: (+1) I see that your answer *does* actually answer [this related question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1048045) since you show the sum equal to $\int_0^{\pi/2}\arctan(\sin(x))\,\mathrm{d}x$, which I showed in the first half of my answer to that question (but never posted since that question was closed as a duplicate of this one). I moved the second half of my answer to that question [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1052675).

Comment: @robjohn and RV: How about [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1053127/146687)? Does it have a closed-form?

Comment: RV: How did you get this one $$\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{\text{arcsinh}(w)}{w \sqrt{1+w^{2}}}=I(\infty)-I(1)$$I only know $$\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{\text{arcsinh}(w)}{w \sqrt{1+w^{2}}}=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\text{arcsinh}(w)}{w \sqrt{1+w^{2}}}-\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\text{arcsinh}(w)}{w \sqrt{1+w^{2}}}$$

Comment: @Venus By differentiating inside of the integral we found out that $I'(a) = \frac{\text{arcsinh(a)}}{a\sqrt{1+a^{2}}} $. Now integrate both sides from $1$ to $\infty$.

Comment: I get it now RV. I have upvoted anyway. Please have a look my question. Thanks. ^^

Answer (score 12):

**Determine a Related Generating Function**

Using the Beta function, we get the following identity:
$$
\frac1{\binom{2n}{n}}=(2n+1)\int_0^1t^n(1-t)^n\mathrm{d}t\tag{1}
$$
Thus,
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-4)^nx^{2n}}{(2n+1)\binom{2n}{n}}
&=\int_0^1\frac1{1+4x^2t(1-t)}\mathrm{d}t\tag{2a}\\
&=\int_0^1\frac1{1+x^2-x^2(2t-1)^2}\mathrm{d}t\tag{2b}\\
&=\frac1{1+x^2}\int_0^1\frac1{1-\frac{x^2}{1+x^2}(2t-1)^2}\mathrm{d}t\tag{2c}\\
&=\frac1{1+x^2}\int_{-1}^1\frac1{1-\frac{x^2}{1+x^2}t^2}\frac12\mathrm{d}t\tag{2d}\\
&=\frac1{2x\sqrt{1+x^2}}\int_{-x/\sqrt{1+x^2}}^{x/\sqrt{1+x^2}}\frac1{1-t^2}\mathrm{d}t\tag{2e}\\
&=\frac1{x\sqrt{1+x^2}}\mathrm{arctanh}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\right)\tag{2f}\\
&=\frac1{x\sqrt{1+x^2}}\mathrm{arcsinh}(x)\tag{2g}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(2a)}$: multiply $(1)$ by $\frac{(-4)^nx^{2n}}{2n+1}$ and sum using the formula for the sum of a geometric series
$\text{(2b)}$: rearrange the denominator of the integrand
$\text{(2c)}$: divide numerator and denominator by $1+x^2$
$\text{(2d)}$: substitute $t\mapsto(t+1)/2$
$\text{(2e)}$: substitute $t\mapsto t\sqrt{1+x^2}\,/x$
$\text{(2f)}$: integrate
$\text{(2g)}$: $\tanh(x)=\left.\sinh(x)\middle/\sqrt{1+\sinh^2(x)}\right.$

---

**Integrate the Generating Function to Evaluate the Sum**
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-4)^n}{(2n+1)^2\binom{2n}{n}}
&=\int_0^1\frac1{x\sqrt{1+x^2}}\mathrm{arcsinh}(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{3a}\\
&=-\int_0^1\mathrm{arcsinh}(x)\frac1{\sqrt{\vphantom{\big|}1+1/x^2}}\mathrm{d}\frac1x\tag{3b}\\
&=-\int_0^1\mathrm{arcsinh}(x)\,\mathrm{d}\,\mathrm{arcsinh}\left(\frac1x\right)\tag{3c}\\
&=-\,\mathrm{arcsinh}^2(1)+\int_0^1\mathrm{arcsinh}\left(\frac1x\right)\,\mathrm{d}\,\mathrm{arcsinh}(x)\tag{3d}\\
&=-\,\mathrm{arcsinh}^2(1)-\int_1^\infty\mathrm{arcsinh}(x)\,\mathrm{d}\,\mathrm{arcsinh}\left(\frac1x\right)\tag{3e}\\
&=-\,\mathrm{arcsinh}^2(1)+\int_1^\infty\frac1{x\sqrt{1+x^2}}\mathrm{arcsinh}(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{3f}\\
&=-\frac12\,\mathrm{arcsinh}^2(1)+\frac12\int_0^\infty\frac1{x\sqrt{1+x^2}}\mathrm{arcsinh}(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{3g}\\
&=-\frac12\,\mathrm{arcsinh}^2(1)+\frac12\int_0^\infty\frac{t\,\mathrm{d}t}{\sinh(t)}\tag{3h}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(3a)}$: integrate $\text{(2g)}$
$\text{(3b)}$: pull a factor of $x$ from the square root
$\text{(3c)}$: prepare to integrate by parts
$\text{(3d)}$: integrate by parts
$\text{(3e)}$: substitute $x\mapsto1/x$
$\text{(3f)}$: $\mathrm{d}\,\mathrm{arcsinh}\left(\frac1x\right)=-\frac1{x\sqrt{1+x^2}}\,\mathrm{d}x$
$\text{(3g)}$: average $\text{(3a)}$ and $\text{(3f)}$
$\text{(3h)}$: substitute $x=\sinh(t)$

Expand $\frac1{\sinh(x)}$ as a series in $e^{-kt}$:
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty\frac{t\,\mathrm{dt}}{\sinh(t)}
&=\int_0^\infty\sum_{k=0}^\infty2t\,e^{-(2k+1)t}\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac2{(2k+1)^2}\\
&=\frac{\pi^2}4\tag{4}
\end{align}
$$
Combining $(3)$ and $(4)$ yields
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-4)^n}{(2n+1)^2\binom{2n}{n}}
&=\frac{\pi^2}8-\frac12\mathrm{arcsinh}^2(1)\tag{5}
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 8):

Here is a little something. Along the same line as your thoughts.

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k}4^{k}}{(2k+1)^{2}\binom{2k}{k}}$$

$$=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k}4^{k}k!k!}{(2k+1)(2k+1)(2k)!}$$

$$=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k}4^{k}k!k!}{(2k+1)(2k+1)!}$$

$$=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k}4^{k}\Gamma(k+1)\Gamma(k+1)}{(2k+1)\Gamma(2k+2)}$$

$$=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k}4^{k}\beta(k+1,k+1)}{2k+1}$$

$$=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k}}{2k+1}\int_{0}^{1}(4x(1-x))^{n}dx$$

$$=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k}}{2k+1}\int_{0}^{1}(1-(2x-1)^{2})^{n}dx$$

Let $t=2x-1$

$$1/2\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k}}{2k+1}\int_{-1}^{1}(1-t^{2})^{n}dt$$

$$=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k}}{2k+1}\int_{0}^{1}(1-t^{2})^{n}dt$$

let $t=\sin(x)$

$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos^{2}(x)\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k}\cos^{2k-1}}{2k+1}dx$$

Note the series is arctan at cos(x)

$$=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\tan^{-1}(\cos(x))dx$$

Parts:

$u=\tan^{-1}(\cos(x)), \;\ dv=dx, \;\ du=\frac{-\sin(x)}{1+\cos^{2}(x)}dx, \;\ v=x$

$$0+\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{x\sin(x)}{1+\cos^{2}(x)}dx$$

This is as far as I have gotten for now. It seems to me this may have been done on the site at some point if we can find it.

See here for the evaluation of this integral.  SOS done it sometime back.

http://sos440.tistory.com/83

Comment: That's the integral from where I got the sum. I was trying to solve that integral and got stuck at the sum.

Comment: Oh, OK. I did not realize that. Well, that sin cos integral looks familiar. I bet it is on the site somewhere.

Comment: I added a link to the eval of that last integral. SOS done it on his blog. Something very similar anyway.

Comment: Thank you for the link Cody, SOS evaluated it nicely. :)

Comment: @Aryabhata: I really did not know if that was a common practice. I am sorry, I will be more careful next time. :)

Comment: @PranavArora: No problem :-)