# Closed-form of $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\;(-1)^n \frac{\left(2-\sqrt{3}\right)^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)^2\quad}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, summation, closed-form

The following question is purely my curiosity. During my calculation to answer @Chris'ssis's question in chat room I encountered this series
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\; \frac{\left(2-\sqrt{3}\right)^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)^2\quad\ \,\,}$$
and I knew how to find its closed-form. Now, I am interested in knowing the closed-form of the following series
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\;(-1)^n \frac{\left(2-\sqrt{3}\right)^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)^2\quad\ \,\,}$$
Is it possible to find its closed-form? I have a hunch it has a closed-form since the first series has it. Honestly, I am totally clueless about this one. Any idea? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Would you consider an answer using the polylog function to be closed-form?

Comment: @RobertIsrael Yes, you may post it if you know it (I believe so). ^^

Comment: Mathematica says $$-\left(\sqrt{3}-2\right) \, _3F_2\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},1;\frac{3}{2},\frac{3}{2};-7+4 \sqrt{3}\right)$$ Yuckk!!

Comment: @Integrator True!

Comment: @Venus: is there any reason not to use $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\;(-1)^n \frac{\left(2-\sqrt{3}\right)^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)^2\quad\ \,}$$ so that there is no long bar at the left of the fraction?

Comment: @robjohn I want to make the numerator & denominator are nicely centered. I'll consider yours when I'm online using my PC

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**First Approach**

Using [`PolyLog[2,x]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PolyLog.html), aka $\mathrm{Li}_2(x)$, we can compute the sum
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)^2}
&=\mathrm{Li}_2(x)-\tfrac14\mathrm{Li}_2(x^2)
\end{align}
$$
Therefore, we have
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)^2}
&=-i\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(ix)^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)^2}\\
&=-i\left[\mathrm{Li}_2(ix)-\tfrac14\mathrm{Li}_2(-x^2)\right]
\end{align}
$$
Plugging in $x=2-\sqrt3$ gives
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{(2-\sqrt3)^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)^2}
&=-i\left[\mathrm{Li}_2(i(2-\sqrt3))-\tfrac14\mathrm{Li}_2(4\sqrt3-7)\right]\\
&\doteq0.26586495827930698269
\end{align}
$$
The last value is computed using Mathematica 8 from the $\mathrm{Li}_2$ formula:

`-I(PolyLog[2,I(2 - Sqrt[3])]-1/4PolyLog[2,4Sqrt[3]-7])`

---

**Second Approach**

Using the Lerch Transcendent,
$$
\Phi(z,s,a)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{z^k}{(a+k)^s}
$$
we get
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{(2-\sqrt3)^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)^2}
&=\frac{2-\sqrt3}4\Phi\left(4\sqrt3-7,2,\tfrac12\right)\\
&\doteq0.26586495827930698269
\end{align}
$$
The last value is computed using Mathematica 8 from the $\Phi$ formula:

`(2-Sqrt[3])/4LerchPhi[4Sqrt[3]-7,2,1/2]`

---

**Third Approach**

In my opinion, this gives the best closed form.

As in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1052675), we can look at a related generating function.
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k\frac{t^{2k+1}}{2k+1}=\arctan(t)\tag{1}
$$
Dividing $(1)$ by $t$ and integrating gives
$$
\begin{align}
\hspace{-1.5cm}
\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k\frac{(2-\sqrt3)^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)^2}
&=\int_0^{2-\sqrt3}\frac{\arctan(t)}{t}\mathrm{d}t\tag{2a}\\
&=\int_0^{\pi/12}x\,\mathrm{d}\log(\tan(x))\tag{2b}\\
&=\frac\pi{12}\log(2-\sqrt3)-\int_0^{\pi/12}\log(\tan(x))\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{2c}\\
&=\frac\pi{12}\log(2-\sqrt3)+2\int_0^{\pi/12}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{\cos((4k+2)x)}{2k+1}\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{2d}\\
&=\frac\pi{12}\log(2-\sqrt3)+\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{\sin((2k+1)\pi/6)}{(2k+1)^2}\tag{2e}\\
&=\frac\pi{12}\log(2-\sqrt3)+\frac12\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)^2}+\frac32\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{(6k+3)^2}\tag{2f}\\
&=\frac\pi{12}\log(2-\sqrt3)+\frac23\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)^2}\tag{2g}\\
&=\frac\pi{12}\log(2-\sqrt3)+\frac23\mathrm{G}\tag{2h}\\[12pt]
&\doteq0.26586495827930698269
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(2a)}$: divide $(1)$ by $t$ and integrate
$\text{(2b)}$: substitute $t=\tan(x)$
$\text{(2c)}$: integrate by parts
$\text{(2d)}$: $\log(\tan(x))=-2\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty\frac{\cos((4k+2)x)}{2k+1}$
$\text{(2e)}$: integrate
$\text{(2f)}$: details below
$\text{(2g)}$: $\frac12+\frac32\cdot\frac19=\frac23$
$\text{(2h)}$: $\mathrm{G}=\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)^2}$ is [Catalan's Constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_constant)
The last value is computed using Mathematica 8 from $\text{(2h)}$:

`Pi/12Log[2-Sqrt[3]]+2/3Catalan`

**Details of $\mathbf{(2f)}$**

$\begin{align}
\sin((2k+1)\pi/6)&=\left(\frac12,\quad1\ \ ,\frac12,-\frac12,\,-1\,,-\frac12,\frac12,\quad1\ \ ,\frac12,\dots\right)\\
&=\left(\frac12,-\frac12,\frac12,-\frac12,\ \ \frac12,-\frac12,\frac12,-\frac12,\frac12,\dots\right)\\
&+\left(\ 0\ ,\quad\frac32,\ 0\ ,\quad\,0\ ,-\frac32,\quad\,0\ ,\ 0\ ,\quad\frac32,\ 0\ ,\dots\right)\\
2k+1
&=(\ \ \,1\,,\quad\ 3\,,\ \,5\,,\quad\ 7\,,\quad\ 9\,,\quad11,13,\ \ \ 15\,,17\,,\dots)
\end{align}$

Note that the $\pm\frac32$ corrections are at positions where $2k+1$ is $3$ times an odd number. That is,
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{\sin((2k+1)\pi/6)}{(2k+1)^2}
=\frac12\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)^2}
+\frac32\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{(6k+3)^2}
$$
which justifies $\text{(2f)}$.

Comment: would the downvoter care to comment?

Comment: I don't understand this, but I won't down-vote for that!

Comment: Very nice & detail answer robjohn. Just ignore the downvoter, he knows nothing the beauty of your answer. Don't let his action drive you mad. I'll choose your answer, I hope Chris's sis doesn't mind. :-)

Comment: @Integrator: what is it you don't understand?

Comment: @robjohn (+1) Awesome ! :-)

Answer (score 2):

The second serie has not elementary sum: see http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LerchTranscendent.html

Comment: It has an elementary sum if you allow Catalan's Constant.