# $\int^{\pi/2}_{0}\frac{\theta \cos(\theta)}{1+\sin^{2}(\theta)}$ through complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, definite-integrals, parametrization

It is known (can be deduced in one turn) from [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/855517/evaluating-a-sum-involving-binomial-coefficient-in-denominator) that 
$$
I=\int^{\pi/2}_{0}\frac{\theta \cos(\theta)}{1+\sin^{2}(\theta)}d\theta=\frac{1}{2}\ln^2(1+\sqrt{2})
$$
I'm trying to use different approach of evaluation:

1. Generalize with parametrization: $\theta\to \arccos(b\cos(\theta))$. $b\in[-1,1]$
2. Differentiate over $b$: $$\frac{\partial I}{\partial b}=-\int^{\pi/2}_{0}\frac{\cos^2(\theta)}{(1+\sin^{2}(\theta))\sqrt{1-b^2\cos^2(\theta)}}d\theta$$ Note: argument is continuous at all point exept $\theta=\pi k, k\in\mathbb{Z}, b=\pm1$.
3. Use symmetry of reflection: $$-\frac{1}{2}\int^{\pi/2}_{-\pi/2}\frac{\cos^2(\theta)}{(1+\sin^{2}(\theta))\sqrt{1-b^2\cos^2(\theta)}}d\theta$$
4. Shift $\theta\to\theta +\pi/2$:  $$-\frac{1}{2}\int^{\pi}_{0}\frac{\sin^2(\theta)}{(1+\cos^{2}(\theta))\sqrt{1-b^2\sin^2(\theta)}}d\theta$$
5. Use identities: $\cos^2(\theta)=\frac{1+\cos(2\theta)}{2},\sin^2(\theta)=\frac{1-\cos(2\theta)}{2}$ and substitute $t=2\theta$:   $$-\frac{1}{4}\int^{2\pi}_{0}\frac{1-\cos(t)}{(3+\cos(t))\sqrt{1-\frac{b^2}{2}(1-\cos(t))}}dt$$
6. Use substitution from complex analysis: $\cos(t)=\frac{z^2+1}{2z},dt=\frac{dz}{iz}$, which after simplification gives: $$\frac{1}{2|b|i}\int_{|z|=1}\frac{z^2-2z+1}{(z^2+6z+1)\sqrt{z^2+\left(\frac{4}{b^2}-2\right)z+1}}\frac{dz}{\sqrt{z}}$$
7. Nonzero residue only at $z_1=-3+2\sqrt{2}$, which after all simplifications leads to $$\frac{\partial I}{\partial b}=\frac{\pi}{2i}\frac{1}{\sqrt{b^2-\frac{1}{2}}}$$

Which definitely is not right, because for $b>\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$ result appears to be complex, while it should be real. So, I wonder where I made a mistake.

Comment: write $2 \int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{x \cos(x)}{1+\sin^2(x)}= \int_0^{\pi}\frac{x \cos(x)}{1+\sin^2(x)}+\pi \int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{ \cos(x)}{1+\sin^2(x)}$. The latter integral is standard whereas the first one can be tackled by complex analysis as nicely explained here: http://residuetheorem.com/2014/12/27/a-tale-of-two-integrals/

Comment: @tired: thank you, it is exactly what I looked for

Comment: Don't think the proposed duplicate targets apply. The question here is "I wonder where I made a mistake"  or at least asking for a derivation that's very close to his.

Answer (score 2):

A real-analytic approach. Through integration by parts we have
$$ I = \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{\theta\cos\theta}{1+\sin^2\theta}\,d\theta=\frac{\pi^2}{8}-\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\arctan(\sin\theta)\,d\theta \tag{1}$$
but since
$$ \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin(\theta)^{2n+1}\,d\theta = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}\,\Gamma\left(n+1\right)}{2\,\Gamma(n+\frac{3}{2})}\tag{2} $$
by exploiting the Taylor series of the arctangent function and performing termwise integration, we have, after some simplification:
$$ I = \frac{\pi^2}{8}-\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^n 4^n}{(2n+1)^2\binom{2n}{n}} \tag{3}$$
and $I$ [can be written in terms of a squared (hyperbolic) arcsine](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/878477/a-closed-form-of-sum-k-0-infty-frac-1k1k-gamma2-left-frack2):
$$ I = \frac{1}{2}\text{arcsinh}^2(1) = \color{red}{\frac{1}{2}\log^2(1+\sqrt{2})}\tag{4}$$
as wanted.

Comment: Thank you for attention, but this answer overlaps with linked one and says nothing about why complex analysis aproach fails, which is the main question

Comment: @KostiantynLapchevskyi: it does not fail! In the linked answer there are multiple approaches to prove the key identity about the squared arcsine, and one of them exploits complex analysis.

Comment: We may directly exploit the residue theorem, but we have to be careful in dealing with the square root branch point. **Or** we may remove the branch point through a suitable substitution and deal with a simpler integral.

Comment: Maybe it just me, but not seeing complex analysis among those approaches. However, you're right regarding beeing careful with branch points. Most likely that I was wrong thinking that small (almost) circle around $z=0$ retuns $0$.